# Change "out of stock" message for single product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I know how to change the "Out of stock" message for all products.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {

    // Change In Stock Text
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Available!', 'woocommerce');
    }
    // Change Out of Stock Text
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Sold Out', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

But how to change the message for a single product in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check for the id of that specific product.

sample

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {

    // Change In Stock Text
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        if ( $_product->get_id() == 200 ) {
            $availability['availability'] = __('Available for 2 days!', 'woocommerce');
        }
        $availability['availability'] = __('Available!', 'woocommerce');
    }

    // Change Out of Stock Text
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Sold Out', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `is_single()` function.
This function can take the product (post) ID as a parameter.

Assuming that your product has an ID of '17'.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {

    // Change In Stock Text
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Available!', 'woocommerce');
    }
    // Change Out of Stock Text
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Sold Out', 'woocommerce');
    }

    if (( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) && (is_single('17')) ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Custom Messsage', 'woocommerce');
    }

    return $availability;
}
```